# function default value not defined

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm trying to use

```
def my_function(a,b)
```

If I  try to print function like this
`print(my_function())`, when values start from none, I get
"missing 2 required positional arguments"

I want to use default value so when I use, `print(my_function())`,
`a=10` and `b=a`.

So I tried

```
def my_function(a=10,b=a)
```

and I got `a not defined`.

I don't want to define `a` before with global.

Is it possible? or something like this

```
def my_function(a,b)
    if a == None:
        a = 10
    if b == None:
        b = a
```

This didn't work either when I used `print(my_function())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the *default* to `None`:

```
def my_function(a=10, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
```

Here the default for `a` is `10`, and `b` is set to `a` if left to the default value.

If you need to accept `None` as well, pick a different, unique default to act as a sentinel. An instance of `object()` is an oft-used convention:

```
_sentinel = object()

def my_function(a=10, b=_sentinel):
    if b is _sentinel:
        b = a
```

Now you can call `my_function(11, None)` and `b` will be set to `None`, call it without specifying `b` (e.g. `my_function()` or `my_function(42)`, and `b` will be set to whatever `a` was set to.

Unless a parameter has a default (e.g. is a keyword parameter), they are *required*.

Comment: `Ellipsis` is sometimes a good sentinel value when you need to accept `None`. It's built into Python but is used for hardly anything outside of writing `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

Comment: @kindall: I prefer being explicit about this. `Ellipsis` is a big documentation WTF; it looks out of place, and it is not clear that you are just using it as a sentinel. The same applies to `NotImplemented`.

Comment: Really, *no* sentinel value is very self-documenting if you're just going to replace it with some other value (e.g. empty list) in the code itself. I guess you could name your sentinel something like `DefaultEmptyList` or whatever.

Comment: @kindall: `_sentinel` is *clearly* documenting what function it serves. `Ellipsis` does not.

Comment: @kindall To get the name in the repr, you can use a class: `class _Sentinel: pass` `_sentinel = _Sentinel()` ... `help(my_function)` -> `... my_function(a=10, b=<..._Sentinel object at 0x...>)`

Answer (score 0):

This function my_function(a,b) expected two positional arguments without default value so It can't be called without them passed

So the main question how can we pass two argument so that second is set to first if not passed

There are two way for this:

kwargs unpacking

```
def my_function(a=10, **kwargs):
    b = kwargs.get('b', a)
```

`sentinel` as default Value

```
_sentinel = object()
def my_function(a=10, b=_sentinel):
    if b is _sentinel:
        b = a
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum! I thing you can't define `my_function` like this. But you can use a decorator to hide the default values computation.

For example:

```
import functools


def my_decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(a=10, b=None):
        if b is None:
            b = a
        return f(a, b)
    return wrapper
```

You can then define your function like this:

```
@my_decorator
def my_function(a, b):
    return (a, b)
```

You can use your function with zero, one or two parameters:

```
>>> print(my_function())
(10, 10)
>>> print(my_function(5))
(5, 5)
>>> print(my_function(5, 12))
(5, 12)
```